# Iperf client reporting too high throughput in Mininet with TCLinks

Tags: mininet, iperf

I'm using Mininet to test out achieved throughputs for different congestion control algorithms. Now I'm seeing something that does not really make sense to me. When running a standard Mininet network with TCLinks that have a bandwidth and delay, iperf and iperf3 on the client both report impossible throughputs (higher than the bandwidth of the links). The server reports the correct numbers.

Reproduction steps:

```
sudo mn --link tc,bw=10,delay=10ms
iperf
```

Output:

```
sudo mn --link tc,bw=10,delay=10ms
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2 
*** Adding switches:
s1 
*** Adding links:
(10.00Mbit 10ms delay) (10.00Mbit 10ms delay) (h1, s1) (10.00Mbit 10ms delay) (10.00Mbit 10ms delay) (h2, s1) 
*** Configuring hosts
h1 h2 
*** Starting controller
c0 
*** Starting 1 switches
s1 ...(10.00Mbit 10ms delay) (10.00Mbit 10ms delay) 
*** Starting CLI:
mininet> iperf
*** Iperf: testing TCP bandwidth between h1 and h2 
*** Results: ['9.50 Mbits/sec', '11.8 Mbits/sec']
```

I would expect to see throughputs just below 10 Mbps for both the client and the server but the client reaches a throughput of around 12 Mbps.

Has anyone a good explanation to this? Is it save to just use the throughput numbers reported by the server for analysis or is there another problem with that?

Comment: can you tell me, what is the result if you run iperf in xterms of the server and client, NOT in mininet CLI

Comment: Same result, the client reports close to 12 Mbps. Btw I'm running Mininet version 2.2.2, compiled from the git repo. But I also verified it with a virtual machine.